# Deleting an array element while moving others down?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm really new to programming, so take this with a grain of salt.

I've made 2 arrays that correspond to eachother; One is a Name array and one is a Phone Number array. The idea is that the spot [1] in NameArray corresponds to spot [1] in the PhoneArray. In other words, I need to keep these 'pairings' in tact.

I'm trying to make a function that deletes one of the spots in the array, and shifts everything down one, as to fill the space left empty by the deleted element.

```
  namearray = namearray.Where(f => f != iNum).ToArray();
```

is what I've tried, with iNum being the number corresponding to the element marked for deletion in the array.

I've also tried converting it to a list, removing the item, then array-ing it again.

```
        var namelist = namearray.ToList();
        var phonelist = phonearray.ToList();
        namelist.Remove(txtName.Text);
        phonelist.Remove(txtPhone.Text);
        namearray = namelist.ToArray();
        phonearray = phonelist.ToArray();
        lbName.Items.Clear();
        lbPhone.Items.Clear();
        lbName.Items.AddRange(namearray);
        lbPhone.Items.AddRange(phonearray);
```

with txtName.Text and txtPhone.Text being the strings for deletion in the corresponding list boxes.

Can someone suggest a better way to do it / What I'm doing wrong / How to fix?

Thanks guys
-Zack

Comment: Why not use a List to begin with?  Arrays are not really designed for what you seem to want to use the structure for as they are immutable, meaning they don't change in length.  The only way to use them in this case would be to create a new array after every modification.  Better to go with the List structure when you intend to make modifications.

Comment: Also, if you prefer to stick to using arrays, then you might consider looking into a 2 dimensional array, a matrix, as you could store the names and numbers together.

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be to have an array of a class that contains a Name and Phone Number object:

```
public class PersonData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public PersonData[] data;
```

That way, instead of keeping two arrays in sync, it's one array with all the appropriate data.

Answer (score 0):

If the *namearray*  and *phonearray* contain strings and you know the index of the element to remove (*iNum*) then you need to use the overload of the Where extension that takes a second parameter, the index of the current element in the evaluation

```
namearray = namearray.Where((x, y) => y != iNum).ToArray();
```

However the suggestion to use classes for your task is the correct one. *Namearray* and *Phonearray* (and whatever else you need to handle in future) are to be thought as properties of a `Person` class and instead of using arrays use a `List<Person>`

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public string Phone {get; set;}

}

List<Person> people = new List<Person>()
{
    {new Person() {FirstName="Steve", LastName="OHara", Phone="123456"}},
    {new Person() {FirstName="Mark", LastName="Noname", Phone="789012"}}
};
```

In this scenarion removing an item knowing the LastName could be written as

```
people = people.Where(x => x.LastName != "OHara").ToList();
```

(or as before using the index in the list of the element to remove)

```
people = people.Where((x, y) => y != iNum).ToArray();
```

Comment: Hey mate, thanks a million for the reply -- I run this code                                           ` lbName.Items.Remove(txtName.Text);
            lbPhone.Items.Remove(txtPhone.Text);
            namearray = namearray.Where((x, y) => y != iNumName).ToArray();
            phonearray = phonearray.Where((x, y) => y != iNumPhone).ToArray();
            lbName.Items.AddRange(namearray);
            lbPhone.Items.AddRange(phonearray); `                               -- and the funniest thing happens. It seems to add items to the list boxes, doubling the amount of items each time!

Comment: Of course your need to clear the items before readding again the previous items. Call lbName.Items,Clear() before the AddRange line. But why? Having removed the line from the lbName with RemoveAt you don't need to readd everything again

Answer (score 0):

Try a loop through both arrays, moving the values of each down an index each time.

Start the loop at the index of the value you want to delete. So you would find the [`IndexOf(T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187(v=vs.110).aspx) the value you want, storing it as `deleteIndex` and run the loop starting from that index.

When you hit the end of the array, set the last value as null or string.Empty (depending what value type the array holds).

A bit like this:

```
var deleteIndex = namearray.IndexOf("TheStringYouWantToDelete");

for (int i = deleteIndex; i < namearray.Length; i++)
{
    if (i == namearray.Length - 1) // The "last" item in the array.
    {
        namearray[i] = string.Empty; // Or null, or your chosen "empty" value.
        phonearray[i] = string.Empty; // Or null, or your chosen "empty" value.
    }
    else
    {
        namearray[i] = namearray[i+1];
        phonearray[i] = phonearray[i+1];
    }
}
```

This will work for deleting and moving values 'down' in index.

You could also rewrite the code for moving them the other way, as it would work similarly.

Reordering them completely? Different ball game...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers provide some better design suggestions, but if you're using ListBoxes and want to stick with arrays, you can do this to synchronize them:

```
     int idx = lbName.Items.IndexOf(txtName.Text);
     if (idx > -1)
     {
        lbName.Items.RemoveAt(idx);
        lbPhone.Items.RemoveAt(idx);
     }
     namearray = lbName.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray<string>();
     phonearray = lbPhone.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary instead.

```
Dictionary<string, string> phoneBook = new Dictionary<string, string>();
phoneBook["Foo"] = "1234567890";
phoneBook["Bar"] = "0987654321";
phoneBook.Remove("Bar");
```